# Why google colab showing different output

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am having code to extract text from wav file

```
# read specific file
from glob import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import time

r = sr.Recognizer()

start_time = datetime.now()
print("Start Time : " + str(start_time))

text=""
count= 0
err=0
for f in glob('audio_10001*.wav*'):
    print(f)
    with sr.AudioFile(f) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
        try:
           s = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-IN')
           text=text+s
        except Exception as e:
             print("Exception: "+str(e))
             err=1
             # text=text+"***************Missing ***********************"
             # print(text)
             # raise e
            
        count=count+1
        if count > 3 :
           break
        time.sleep(5)
        
    t = open('new.txt', 'a')
    t.write('\n')
    t.write(f + '\n')   
    t.write(text.capitalize() + '\n')
    t.write("***************************************")
    t.close()

end_time = datetime.now()
print("End Time : " + str(end_time))
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

I am running a code on my laptop and google colab ( free version ) both are showing different output

Google colab

```
Anybody want welcome to all participants and speakers we have a very very speaker with us today mr nandhakumar and a very interesting topics going to be first one on the agriculture
```

My Laptop

```
Very very warm welcome to all participants and our speakers we have a very very speaker with us today mr nandkumar on the order of you know him and a very very interesting topic with mr anand kumar is going to be famous on on the checking of agriculture and put the pros and cons what we will discuss you also have the committee head of our policy research focuses on shukla and co-chair internal pan with us today good evening everyone and thank you anand kumar
```

Why it is showing huge difference between sentences and length of output ? can you pl help

Thanks

Comment: Hi Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi Any updates to resolve this ? Thanks